# Highcharts series data select point video sync

Tags: video, highcharts, synchronization, series

I need some help synchronizing a video timeline with the data select point of the curve's series. 
To better explain what I want to do and what I did until now, take a look at [my example](http://jsfiddle.net/wanderly/59s7ao0s/)

I need that the selected dot stop blinking. I need a more fluid movement. 
I tried some tricks but without success.

Any help will be very welcome.

```
var video = document.getElementById("Video");

$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'spline',
            margin: [0, 0, 0, 0]
        },
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        exporting: {
            enabled: false
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: ''
        },
        xAxis: {
            lineWidth: 0,
            minorGridLineWidth: 0,
            lineColor: 'transparent',
            minorTickLength: 0,
            tickLength: 0,
            text: null,
            labels: {
                enabled: false
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: null
            },
            max: 100,
            min: 0,
            minorGridLineWidth: 0,
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            alternateGridColor: null,
            labels: {
                enabled: false
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 70.345255,
                color: '#62acdf',
                dashStyle: 'dot',
                width: 1
            }, {
                value: 29.654745,
                color: '#62acdf',
                dashStyle: 'dot',
                width: 1
            }],
            plotBands: [{
                from: 29.654745,
                to: 70.345255,
                color: 'rgba(98,172,223,0.1)'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return this.x / 2 + 's<br>' + '<span style="color:' + this.series.color + '">●</span> ' + this.series.name + ': <b> ' + this.y.toFixed(2) + '</b>';
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                point: {
                    events: {
                        click: function () {
                            video.currentTime = (this.x / 2);
                            video.pause();
                        }
                    }
                },
                marker: {
                    radius: 1,
                    states: {
                        select: {
                            radius: 3,
                            fillColor: '#62acdf',
                            lineColor: '#62acdf',
                            lineWidth: 4
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            spline: {
                lineWidth: 2,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        lineWidth: 2
                    }
                },
                marker: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'txt',
            color: '#62acdf',
            data: [{
                y: 30.866000,
                color: '#BF0B23',
                radius: 0
            }, {
                y: 42.868000,
                color: '#BF0B23',
                radius: 0
            }, {
                y: 46.859000,
                color: '#BF0B23',
                radius: 0
            }, {
                y: 51.062000,
                color: '#BF0B23',
                radius: 0
            }, {
                y: 68.203000,
                color: '#BF0B23',
                radius: 0
            }, {
                y: 56.879000,
                color: '#BF0B23',
                radius: 0
            },
            72.250000, {
                y: 35.184000,
                color: '#BF0B23',
                radius: 0
            }, {
                y: 66.606000,
                color: '#BF0B23',
                radius: 0
            }, {
                y: 34.417000,
                color: '#BF0B23',
                radius: 0
            },
            19.729000, 22.328000, 26.512000, 8.023900, 23.775000, 19.330000, 18.326000, {
                y: 43.427000,
                color: '#BF0B23',
                radius: 0
            }, {
                y: 37.062000,
                color: '#BF0B23',
                radius: 0
            }, {
                y: 49.789000,
                color: '#BF0B23',
                radius: 0
            }, {
                y: 42.211000,
                color: '#BF0B23',
                radius: 0
            }, {
                y: 50.581000,
                color: '#BF0B23',
                radius: 0
            },
            16.836000, 14.436000, 9.622700, 6.944100, 28.147000, 16.000000, {
                y: 45.813000,
                color: '#BF0B23',
                radius: 0
            }, {
                y: 48.373000,
                color: '#BF0B23',
                radius: 0
            }, {
                y: 64.385000,
                color: '#BF0B23',
                radius: 0
            }, {
                y: 42.571000,
                color: '#BF0B23',
                radius: 0
            }, {
                y: 65.816000,
                color: '#BF0B23',
                radius: 0
            },
            10.839000, 21.495000, {
                y: 47.478000,
                color: '#BF0B23',
                radius: 0
            },
            10.273000, 29.029000, 21.656000, 15.887000, 15.531000, {
                y: 55.848000,
                color: '#BF0B23',
                radius: 0
            },
            70.714000, {
                y: 50.479000,
                color: '#BF0B23',
                radius: 0
            }, {
                y: 64.778000,
                color: '#BF0B23',
                radius: 0
            }, {
                y: 67.984000,
                color: '#BF0B23',
                radius: 0
            }, {
                y: 60.161000,
                color: '#BF0B23',
                radius: 0
            }, {
                y: 32.788000,
                color: '#BF0B23',
                radius: 0
            },
            27.038000, {
                y: 30.471000,
                color: '#BF0B23',
                radius: 0
            },
            27.768000, {
                y: 34.068000,
                color: '#BF0B23',
                radius: 0
            }, {
                y: 43.744000,
                color: '#BF0B23',
                radius: 0
            },
            72.629000, {
                y: 52.510000,
                color: '#BF0B23',
                radius: 0
            }, {
                y: 55.916000,
                color: '#BF0B23',
                radius: 0
            }, {
                y: 64.293000,
                color: '#BF0B23',
                radius: 0
            },
            74.891000, {
                y: 48.053000,
                color: '#BF0B23',
                radius: 0
            },
            22.576000, {
                y: 50.433000,
                color: '#BF0B23',
                radius: 0
            }, ]
        }],
        navigation: {
            menuItemStyle: {
                fontSize: '10px'
            }
        }
    });
});
var curves = $('#container').highcharts();
video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function () {
    var percent = (this.currentTime / this.duration);
    var posicao = (percent * curves.series[0].data.length).toFixed(0);
    curves.series[0].data[posicao].select();

}, false);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sync the variable using the event 'seeked'.
When the user click on the timeline, this event is fired when the video actually go the frame the user click. Then you should sync `posicao` with the variable who is holding the last known position.

Comment: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/wanderly/59s7ao0s/1/) finally I got what I need. check my final code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like your `video.addEventListener` is firing too much. This is causing the "blinking" because it is selecting the same point over and over again. Maybe check to see if the `posicao` is different from the last time it ran and if it isnt just exit. If it is different then do the `select()`.

Comment: I tryed before, but I always lose the last position when click on video's timeline. I'm missing something.